# Add to header to OAuth2 link in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, oauth-2.0

So my application uses the Box.com API and, in order to be able to download a file, I have to send a GET request to https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/content.

Thing is, in the header, there has to be this:

Authorization: Bearer TOKEN

How do I do this in ruby on rails in order for when the user clicks the link, the download proceeds smoothly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ruby-box gem](https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box)

It's a ruby client for the Box 2.0 api, if you look at the README, it shows you how to get authorized and download a file

Comment: I have and I am using it. The thing is, the request has to be made by the client to the API, as I don't want the file to pass through my server. I was thinking maybe rails had a way to setup a link to a website with a pre-defined header. Does it? If it does not, can it be done using javascript?